# Find the equation of the generators of $yz+2zx+3xy+6=0$ that pass through $(0,-3,2)$.

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

Find the equation of the generators of $yz+2zx+3xy+6=0$ that pass through $(0,-3,2)$.

How to solve such types of problem. I have no idea. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a line $r$ passing through $P=(0,-3,2)$ and all lying on the hyperboloid defined by the given equation. A generic point on $r$ has coordinates $(at,-3+bt,2+ct)$: you can substitute these into the hyperboloid equation and get an equation which has to be satisfied for all values of $t$. This can only happen if the coefficients of $t$ and $t^2$ in that equation vanish: from this condition you can find $a$, $b$ and $c$ (up to a common multiplier, of course).